# URL rewriting PHP losing querystring

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a dynamic URL like

```
<domainname>/sub/cl/<phpfile.php>?c=123
```

phpfile.php can be any php file which comes in run time

/sub/cl/ is a folder path.

i have use this code in .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^sub/cl/new-file/([0-9]+)/?$ sub/cl/newfile.php?c=$1 [NC,L]
```

this is correctly redirecting to the newfile.php when i hit /sub/cl/new-file/321/  but sub/cl/ get appended before all css and js which are in root and also c=321 get lost

Please help me what m doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

if your problem is only query string insert `[QSA]` flag to to the rule. JS/CSS/IMG files are losing because the rewrite works for every request. Over come this issue by adding `RewriteCond`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f #Files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d #Directories
```

further reading
[Apache Mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Comment: Thanks, i have used this RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/([0-9]+)/$ $1.php?c=$1 [NC,L] still it appended in css, and js can u give me some example if u have how to omit to append before css and js

Comment: try adding both file and directory conditions.

Comment: RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/$ $1.php?c=$2&tpk=$3 [NC,QSA] this is working but RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/$ $1.php?c=$2&tpk=$3 [NC,QSA] not workingany idea?